# change the itemize from bullet to square

Tags: lists, itemize

I am trying to change the itemize symbols. Using

```
\begin{itemize}
 \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\blacksquare$} 
 \item  An extensively analysis 
\end{itemize}
```

the problem is the dimension of the square. it is quite big with respect the bullet one. Any idea about that?

Comment: For future readers: `\blacksquare` comes from `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that an empty square box can be obtained from the same package with `\square`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this. It changes the font size just before typesetting the `\blacksquare`. Depending on what you need, other sizes, such as `\tiny` are also available.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
 \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\scriptsize$\blacksquare$}
 \item  An extensively analysis
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26):

I use something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\localtextbulletone}{\textcolor{gray}{\raisebox{.45ex}{\rule{.6ex}{.6ex}}}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\localtextbulletone}
\begin{itemize}
\item  An extensively analysis
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

so I'm able to change the size. The colour is, of course, optional.

Comment: could you give me an example of use, please? I tried it but nothing change...

Comment: @doxsi: Incorporated example into the answer. You could of course omit the \newcommand and put the definition into the \renewcommand. I use the symbol additionally outside of the itemize environment, therefore the effort.