# Change the shape of the bullet list

Tags: lyx, itemize

I am trying to change the shape of the bullet list by using Lyx 2.1.0.
The class of my document is `report` (and the language is `French`).

I want to change the form of bullet list dash to another.

Comment: [Welcome to SE.TeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). The label used by the `itemize` environment is defined by the `\labelitemi` command (equal to \textbullet by default). For example, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64892/14497) shows how to change the label from a bullet to a square. (To use the new label throughout your document, you would need to place `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\blacksquare$}` on the preamble.)

Comment: Also have a look on the package `enumitem`. It provides a very easy access to change the bullet labels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you could use the `enumitem` package for this, via the LyX GUI.

1. Document --> Settings --> Modules. Add the module called *Customisable lists (enumitem)*.
2. Create your list.
3. Right click the *first* item in the list, and choose *Itemize options*:

   [image]
4. In the inset that appears, write

   ```
   label=<whatever symbol you want>
   ```

   You can either use LaTeX code directly via an ERT inserted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, or you can use Insert --> Special character --> Symbols, or any mathematical symbol from the math toolbar, by adding an inline math inset, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

#### Examples

- To get the dagger, after writing `label=`, add an inline math inset with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and type `\dagger` to get the dagger symbol.
- To get an em-dash, you can either add an ERT and type `---`, or go to Insert --> Special character --> Symbols, and find the em dash under *General punctuation*.
- There are various cross-shapes under the *Dingbats* group in Insert --> Special character --> Symbols.

  The `pifont` package also contains various cross-shapes. Try adding `\usepackage{pifont}` to the LaTeX preamble, and using `\ding{55}` or `\ding{56}` in an ERT.

  (By the way, tables 248 to 251 of [The Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) lists such symbols from `bbding` and `pifont`.)

How it could look in LyX:

[image]

`.lyx` file for the above screenshot is below. You can save this as a `something.lyx` and open it in LyX.

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage{pifont}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
enumitem
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
List with em-dash:
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
label=
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

---
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset

Lorem ipsum.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
List with cross-shape from Insert --> Special character --> Symbol (
\family typewriter
bbding
\family default
-package):
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
label=✗
\end_layout

\end_inset

Lorem ipsum
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
List with cross-shape from 
\family typewriter
pifont
\family default
:
\end_layout

\begin_layout Itemize
\begin_inset Argument 1
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
label=
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
ding{56}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset

Lorem ipsum
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: How can I get a form of "cross" type ?

Comment: @user1936895 What kind of cross?

Comment: I edited my answer slightly, by the way.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Nice answer. Which symbol did you insert where the package was not added? This sounds like a LyX bug. If you find other bugs in LyX (even if you're not sure they're bugs or if you're not sure if they've been fixed), please send me an email at skostysh@lyx.org or post on http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: @scottkosty It was a checkmark, I think `\Checkmark`. I thought I'd at least check with the final version of 2.1 before posting a bug report.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You might be right that it was fixed. I can't reproduce. Let me know when you upgrade if you can reproduce.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Like this cross http://nsa34.casimages.com/img/2014/04/30/140430035433777635.png

Comment: `\ding{56}` from the `pifont` package is similar.

Comment: @scottkosty I was unable to reproduce it, so must have been fixed.

Comment: Can't I add "Add the module called Customisable lists (enumitem)." under "beamer" document class? I can do that under normal document class.

Comment: @user42459 No, the `enumitem` package doesn’t work with `beamer`.